# code doesnt work after adding child class. can someone point out why?

Tags: python

Here is my code. This worked before the child class. but now i get the following traceback

```
class User:
    """uses the user database for printing their info and greetings"""

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, age, joined_date, sex):
        """set variables for the user info"""
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.full_name = f'{first_name} {last_name}'
        self.age = age
        self.joined_date = joined_date
        self.sex = sex

    def describe_user(self):
        """prints info on the user"""
        prompt = f"{self.full_name.title()}, a {self.sex} of age {self.age}"
        prompt += f" years. Joined on {self.joined_date}."
        print(prompt)

    def greet_user(self):
        """greetings"""
        print(f"Hello, {self.first_name.title()}, how are you doing?")


class Admin(User):
    """subclass for admin"""
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, age, joined_date, sex,):
        """initialise attriibutes of admin"""
        super.__init__(first_name, last_name, age, joined_date, sex)
        self.can_ban_user = True
        self.can_delete_post = True
        self.can_add_post = True

    def show_privileges(self, show):
        prompt = ['']
        if self.can_add_post == True:
            prompt += (f"User can add posts, ")
        if self.can_ban_user == True:
            prompt += (f"User can delete posts")
        if self.can_ban_user == True:
            prompt +=(f"User can ban other users")
        print(prompt)


me = Admin('l', 'na', 21, '19-06-2020', 'male')
me.show_privileges()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\$$$\Desktop\python_work\9-7.py", line 44, in <module>
    me = Admin('l', 'na', 21, '19-06-2020', 'male')
  File "C:\Users\$$$\Desktop\python_work\9-7.py", line 28, in __init__
    super.__init__(first_name, last_name, age, joined_date, sex)
TypeError: descriptor '__init__' requires a 'super' object but received a 'str'
```

Comment: "Here is my code" is not a question.  What exactly is the problem?  If there's an error message, we need to see the full traceback.  If the code doesn't behave as expected, we need to know what it actually does, and what you expected.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Please [edit] the question to clarify. See [mre] for reference, and [ask] if you want more advice.

Comment: You're missing the parentheses to call `super`. It should be `super().__init__(...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your code and there are a couple of problems:

- First, the super() function should be given 2 arguments:

  ```
  super(Admin, self).__init__(first_name, last_name, age, joined_date, sex)
  ```
- Second, your function `show_privileges()` has an argument `show` that you are not using
- Third, your output returns in a dict.

Cheers!

Comment: `First, the super() function should be given 2 arguments:` Not needed in Python 3.

Comment: You can call `super` without arguments now. But yeah, it does need to be called to actually work. Also it's a class, not a function.